# Weird space around svg files when they are the same color

Tags: html, css, svg, browser, format

I am building a Website where there are divs with a `background-color` property next to each other. Between those, there are other divs with a `background-image` property.

When looking at it on my Laptop (Chrome Browser) everything seems fine, but when I look at it on smaller screens there are weird spaces between the divs, around the SVGs. Also, this problem only appears when the divs next to each other have the same color.

To showcase this, here is a simple version of the problem:

[Working version, "wave2" is different color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ6oH.png)

[Buggy version, "wave2" is same color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kLWD.png)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./teststyle.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wave" id="wave-1">wave1</div>
    <div class="space">space</div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave-2">wave2</div>
    <div class="space">space</div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave-3">wave3</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wave {
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 900/50;
}

.space {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}

#wave-1 {
    background-image: url(./imgs/wave-filled.svg);
}

#wave-2 {
    background-image: url(./imgs/wave-2.svg);
}

#wave-3 {
    background-image: url(./imgs/wave-3.svg);
}
```

Non-working SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 900 50">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: gray;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="952" height="131"/>
</svg>
```

The SVGs on the Website I'm working on were created on another Website ([GetWaves](https://getwaves.io/)) and their code looks different from the ones I used on the test site mentioned above (I created those in Illustrator), so I thought maybe thats the reason. After trying other SVGs I came to the conclusion that the same colors are actually the problem.

I also tried this with PNGs but that led to the same problem.

I also have the same problem when looking at the Website in Safari.

I also tried `stroke: currentColor`, `fill: currentColor`, `display: inline-block` and `stroke-width: 0` on the wave class

Comment: These are rounding artefacts from the `aspect-ratio` property. Try adding `.wave { background-size: cover }`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly this did not work.